# Email notification after item delivery magento

Tags: email, magento, notifications

I need to send an email notification to customer after the order is delivered to the customer. Is that thing can be done by default magento, or I have to purchase any module for that. Please help.

Comment: you have to use logistics team api and some team have already module for that.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically depends on you delivery partner. If they can inform you about the order delivery at real time, you can do that. Run a cron job every 15 mins, to pull every delivered order Or check statuses of order which has "processing" or "complete" status in backend. By that you can knowing delivered order, send a notification to customer.